# Eventos JS con botones

Tags: javascript, html5, eventos, canvas

Tengo un duda cuando intento activar evento `ViewFigure1()` muestra la figura en canva, y al darle click al evento `ViewVist_Sup01()` me muestra la vista.

pero al activar las 2 funciones al mismo tiempo, una queda debajo de la otra, como puedo solucionar para que solo muestre una cada vez que las active.

```js
function ViewFigure1(){

var canvas  = document.getElementById('CanvSect1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// linea cental - (BASE CUBO)
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(150, 130);
ctx.lineTo(150, 145);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

// linea derecha central - CUBO 
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(150, 145); // Linea derecha (BASE CUBO)
ctx.lineTo(220, 100);
ctx.lineTo(220, 55); // linea 90° derecha 
ctx.lineTo(190, 75); // conectores linea central superior
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

// linea izquierda central - CUBO
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(150, 145); // Liena izquierda (BASE CUBO)
ctx.lineTo(50, 100);
ctx.lineTo(50, 85); // linea 90° izquierda
// ctx.lineTo(150, 100); // conectores linea central superior
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();    

// linea atras derecha - (BASE CUBO)
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(220, 55); // Linea atras Union Cubo (SUPERIOR)
ctx.lineTo(190, 45); 
// ctx.lineTo(190, 45); // Liena conector cuadros atras Superior
// ctx.lineTo(90, 35);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

// cuadro izquierdo completo
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(150, 30); // Linea atras Union cubo (SUPERIOR) 
ctx.lineTo(120, 20);
ctx.lineTo(90, 35); // Linea izquierda Conector
ctx.lineTo(90, 65);
ctx.lineTo(50, 85); // Conector base Arriba - Base Abajo 
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

        // Segundo cuadro - FORMA CUBO (Vista lateral)
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(150, 30);
        ctx.lineTo(150, 50);
        ctx.lineTo(120, 65);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
// --------------------------------------------

// LINEA INTERMEDIO (Cuadro #1)
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(190, 105);
ctx.lineTo(190, 75);
ctx.lineTo(160, 63); // Liena cuadro 1 (Vista frontal)
// ctx.lineTo(120, 47); // Linea union Cuadro #1 - cuadro #2 (Delantera Superior)
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

        // Linea central cuadro #1 Derecho
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(190, 45);
        ctx.lineTo(190, 65);
        ctx.lineTo(160, 80);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

                // Linea conector inferio atras 
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(190, 65);
                ctx.lineTo(150, 50);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();


// linea inferior cara #2 - #3
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 85); // Linea barra Base 2.0 Izquierda 
ctx.lineTo(85, 100);
// ctx.lineTo(190, 105); // Linea barra base 2.0 (Vista  frontal- lateral)
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

        // Liena conexion Base #1 Base #2 (Vista Lateral)
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(190, 105);
        ctx.lineTo(150, 130);
        ctx.lineTo(150, 130);
        ctx.lineTo(120, 115);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

// --------------------------------------------

    // CUADRO IZQUIERDA
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(150, 30); // Cuadro izquierdo 
    ctx.lineTo(120, 47);
    ctx.lineTo(120, 65);
    ctx.lineTo(160, 80); // // Linea union Cuadro #1 - cuadro #2 (Delantera Inferior)
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

                // LINEA CUADRO IZQUIERDO DELANTERO
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(120, 47);
                ctx.lineTo(90, 35);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();

    // Lineas superior cara #1 - #2 (2)
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(190, 45); // Linea Cuadro #1 Derecha
    ctx.lineTo(160, 63);
    ctx.lineTo(160, 80); // Cuadro #1 derecho conector (BASE INFERIOR DELANTERA)
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    // Lineas CENTRAL BAJO MEDIO
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(190, 105); // LINEA INTERMEDIO (Seperador de Bases)
    ctx.lineTo(90, 65);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

// CUADRO INTERNO MEDIO BASE #1
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(119, 115); // CUADRO INTERNO BASE #1
    ctx.lineTo(135,105);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 90);
    ctx.lineTo(85, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

        // Linea derecha (FRONTAL)
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(119, 115);
        ctx.lineTo(119, 130);
        ctx.lineTo(135, 105);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

        // Linea izquierda (FRONTAL)
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(85, 100);
        ctx.lineTo(85, 115);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 90);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();


// CUADRO IZQUIERDA (linea recta 90° -- IZQUIERDA)
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(120, 20);
ctx.lineTo(120, 50);
ctx.lineTo(90, 65);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
        
        // // Lineea atras conector (INFERIOR)
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(120, 50);
        ctx.lineTo(190, 75);
        ctx.lineTo(190, 45);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
}

function ViewVist_Sup01(){

    var canvas  = document.getElementById('CanvSect1');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // PLANO PRINCIPAL
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(240, 235, 234, 0.9)';
    ctx.strokeRect(25, 15, 250, 120);
    ctx.closePath();

    // ---------- SECCION DERECHA ---------- 
    
    // Cuadro superior
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(249, 16, 16 , 0.7)";
    ctx.fillRect(25, 15, 125, 35);
    ctx.closePath();

    // Cuadro medio
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(250, 250, 4, 0.7)";
    ctx.fillRect(25, 50, 125, 50);
    ctx.closePath();

    // cuadro inferior 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(249, 16, 16 , 0.7)";
    ctx.fillRect(25, 100, 125, 35);
    ctx.closePath();

    // ---------- SECCION IZQUERDA ----------

    // cuadro medio
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
    ctx.fillRect(215, 50, 60, 50);

    // Contorno seccion grande
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)";
    ctx.moveTo(150, 15);
    ctx.lineTo(150, 135);
    ctx.lineTo(275, 135);
    ctx.lineTo(275, 100);
    ctx.lineTo(215, 100);
    ctx.lineTo(215, 50);
    ctx.lineTo(275, 50);
    ctx.lineTo(275, 15);
    ctx.lineTo(150, 15);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}


function ResetCanva01(){
    var canvas  = document.getElementById('CanvSect1');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```html
<div id="Sect_1">
                    <p>Figura 1</p>
                        <canvas id="CanvSect1"></canvas><br>
                            <button id="Figure_01" onclick="ViewFigure1()">Figura</button>
                                <button id="Vist_Sup01" onclick="ViewVist_Sup01()">V. Superior</button>
                                <!-- <button id="Vist_Front01" onclick="ViewVist_Front01()">V. Frontal</button> -->
                                <!-- <button id="Vist_Lat01" onclick="ViewVist_Lat01()">V. Lateral</button> -->
                                    <button id="Reset_01" onclick="ResetCanva01()">Reset</button>
                 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function ViewFigure1() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('CanvSect1');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // linea cental - (BASE CUBO)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(150, 130);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 145);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  // linea derecha central - CUBO 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(150, 145); // Linea derecha (BASE CUBO)
  ctx.lineTo(220, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(220, 55); // linea 90° derecha 
  ctx.lineTo(190, 75); // conectores linea central superior
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // linea izquierda central - CUBO
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(150, 145); // Liena izquierda (BASE CUBO)
  ctx.lineTo(50, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(50, 85); // linea 90° izquierda
  // ctx.lineTo(150, 100); // conectores linea central superior
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // linea atras derecha - (BASE CUBO)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(220, 55); // Linea atras Union Cubo (SUPERIOR)
  ctx.lineTo(190, 45);
  // ctx.lineTo(190, 45); // Liena conector cuadros atras Superior
  // ctx.lineTo(90, 35);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // cuadro izquierdo completo
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(150, 30); // Linea atras Union cubo (SUPERIOR) 
  ctx.lineTo(120, 20);
  ctx.lineTo(90, 35); // Linea izquierda Conector
  ctx.lineTo(90, 65);
  ctx.lineTo(50, 85); // Conector base Arriba - Base Abajo 
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Segundo cuadro - FORMA CUBO (Vista lateral)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(150, 30);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(120, 65);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  // --------------------------------------------

  // LINEA INTERMEDIO (Cuadro #1)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(190, 105);
  ctx.lineTo(190, 75);
  ctx.lineTo(160, 63); // Liena cuadro 1 (Vista frontal)
  // ctx.lineTo(120, 47); // Linea union Cuadro #1 - cuadro #2 (Delantera Superior)
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Linea central cuadro #1 Derecho
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(190, 45);
  ctx.lineTo(190, 65);
  ctx.lineTo(160, 80);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Linea conector inferio atras 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(190, 65);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 50);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();


  // linea inferior cara #2 - #3
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(50, 85); // Linea barra Base 2.0 Izquierda 
  ctx.lineTo(85, 100);
  // ctx.lineTo(190, 105); // Linea barra base 2.0 (Vista  frontal- lateral)
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Liena conexion Base #1 Base #2 (Vista Lateral)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(190, 105);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 130);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 130);
  ctx.lineTo(120, 115);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // --------------------------------------------

  // CUADRO IZQUIERDA
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(150, 30); // Cuadro izquierdo 
  ctx.lineTo(120, 47);
  ctx.lineTo(120, 65);
  ctx.lineTo(160, 80); // // Linea union Cuadro #1 - cuadro #2 (Delantera Inferior)
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // LINEA CUADRO IZQUIERDO DELANTERO
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(120, 47);
  ctx.lineTo(90, 35);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Lineas superior cara #1 - #2 (2)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(190, 45); // Linea Cuadro #1 Derecha
  ctx.lineTo(160, 63);
  ctx.lineTo(160, 80); // Cuadro #1 derecho conector (BASE INFERIOR DELANTERA)
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Lineas CENTRAL BAJO MEDIO
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(190, 105); // LINEA INTERMEDIO (Seperador de Bases)
  ctx.lineTo(90, 65);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // CUADRO INTERNO MEDIO BASE #1
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(119, 115); // CUADRO INTERNO BASE #1
  ctx.lineTo(135, 105);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 90);
  ctx.lineTo(85, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Linea derecha (FRONTAL)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(119, 115);
  ctx.lineTo(119, 130);
  ctx.lineTo(135, 105);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Linea izquierda (FRONTAL)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(85, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(85, 115);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 90);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();


  // CUADRO IZQUIERDA (linea recta 90° -- IZQUIERDA)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(120, 20);
  ctx.lineTo(120, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(90, 65);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // // Lineea atras conector (INFERIOR)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(120, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(190, 75);
  ctx.lineTo(190, 45);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function ViewVist_Sup01() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('CanvSect1');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // PLANO PRINCIPAL
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(240, 235, 234, 0.9)';
  ctx.strokeRect(25, 15, 250, 120);
  ctx.closePath();

  // ---------- SECCION DERECHA ---------- 

  // Cuadro superior
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(249, 16, 16 , 0.7)";
  ctx.fillRect(25, 15, 125, 35);
  ctx.closePath();

  // Cuadro medio
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(250, 250, 4, 0.7)";
  ctx.fillRect(25, 50, 125, 50);
  ctx.closePath();

  // cuadro inferior 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(249, 16, 16 , 0.7)";
  ctx.fillRect(25, 100, 125, 35);
  ctx.closePath();

  // ---------- SECCION IZQUERDA ----------

  // cuadro medio
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
  ctx.fillRect(215, 50, 60, 50);

  // Contorno seccion grande
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)";
  ctx.moveTo(150, 15);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 135);
  ctx.lineTo(275, 135);
  ctx.lineTo(275, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(215, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(215, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(275, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(275, 15);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 15);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}


function ResetCanva01() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('CanvSect1');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```html
<div id="Sect_1">
  <p>Figura 1</p>
  <canvas id="CanvSect1"></canvas><br>

  <button id="Figure_01" onclick="ViewFigure1()">Figura</button>
  <button id="Vist_Sup01" onclick="ViewVist_Sup01()">V. Superior</button>
  <!-- <button id="Vist_Front01" onclick="ViewVist_Front01()">V. Frontal</button> -->
  <!-- <button id="Vist_Lat01" onclick="ViewVist_Lat01()">V. Lateral</button> -->
  <button id="Reset_01" onclick="ResetCanva01()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Lo que te ocurre, es que estas pintando directamente las formas, pero **te estas olvidando de limpiar el canvas antes de mostrar la otra forma**.

Para poder solventar este inconveniente, lo unico que hice, fue usar al principio de las funciones `ViewFigure1` como tambien `ViewVist_Sup01` el metodo `clearRect` de `CanvasRenderingContext2D`, que lo que hace es eliminar cualquier trazado de pixeles que se haya hecho o dibujado en el canvas, para que posteriormente una vez limpiado el canvas se procediera a lo que hace el resto de cada funcion (pintar una figura).

Mas concretamente lo que puse fue esta linea de aqui en ambas funciones al inicio:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

De esta manera, al ejecutar ya sea una funcion o la otra, primero se limpiara el canvas y luego se pintara en el, de esta manera, las figuras nunca quedaran superpuestas.